# Effects of using "=" in object construction

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

Another C++ question, I'm trying to figure out what are the effects of using "=" when constructing objects. Consider:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        int bar;
        int baz;

    public:
        Foo(int bar, int baz)
            :bar(bar), baz(baz) {}
};

int main() {
    Foo foo1{4, 2};
    Foo foo2 = {4, 2};
    Foo foo3 = Foo{4, 2}; // I prefer this one for aesthetic reasons.

    return 0;
}
```

What are the differences and which one should I stick to as a best practice?

Also, while we're on the topic of best practices, I hear adding `explicit` to constructors is a Good Idea™ because of weird behaviour with implicit conversions. So I added `explicit` to the constructor of `Foo`:

```
    public:
        explicit Foo(int bar, int baz)
            :bar(bar), baz(baz) {}
```

Suddenly, this:

```
    Foo foo2 = {4, 2};
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
```

Why is that?

Comment: The two differences that matter: 1) As you've seen, copy initialization doesn't work with explicit constructors. 2) `auto` deduces `std::initializer_list` differently between copy and direct initialization. For the rest, it becomes moot in C++17.

Comment: `Foo foo3 = Foo{4, 2}; // I prefer this one.` I have no idea why. Notionally, it involves a completely pointless extra copy, though in reality a good optimising compiler will undo your mistake. But it just looks verbose and ugly. Why write more than you have to, when it's redundant? `Foo foo{4, 2};` is superior.

Comment: "I hear adding explicit to constructors..." - besides being a dreadfully blanket statement, did the unmentioned author of wherever you heard that mention *why* they considered this a good idea? Did you agree, disagree, or simply not understand that justification? Finally, [this description of `explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) is worth reviewing.

Comment: Also note that the mentioned rule that `auto` would always deduce an `std::initializer_list` was deemed a defect and is fixed in C++17 - where `auto thing = {a, b}` with 2+ elements will still deduce an `std::initializer_list` _but_ e.g. `auto str{ std::to_string(num) };` will now, correctly IMO, deduce the type to be constructed. The very correct rationale for this was that it avoids us having to remember 2 sets of rules - thereby making uniform initialisation, well, uniform. It's worth noting `g++` already backported this to older Standards, but Clang doesn't (which is arguably more polite!)

Comment: @underscore_d "I have no idea why", aesthetics. I don't know the difference between the statements which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well I decided to spare the specifics, but it's to prevent implicit conversions with constructors if I recall correctly, which I thought was a Good Idea™.

Comment: @MemeMaster It's almost as if aesthetics must be subjective or something! It looks bad to me. But there's now an answer that explains the real functional differences. Btw, I would advise against internalising 'good ideas' if you don't understand them.

Comment: @underscore_d It's a result C teaching me to associate "declared, but uninitialised" with no equals sign. Also I also prefer `Foo{4, 2};` as it's being explicit with what is being constructed. Probably Stockholm Syndrome from using Java for a while.

Comment: @MemeMaster `Foo foo{4, 2};` is _totally_ explicit about what is being constructed. There's no other way that code can be interpreted. Hence why uniform initialisation exists and IMO (and I'm sure that of many others) is a superior solution to all other forms of initialisation. It removes all ambiguity and lets initialisation always happen in the same way, finally (at least with C++17 if we include `auto`). C and especially Java are _far_ from relevant when assessing the best way to code in C++.

Comment: @underscore_d "assessing the best way to code in C++" I was just describing my thought process? I don't know what is the "best way to code C++" in this case, which is why I asked question in the first place, sheesh.

Comment: @MemeMaster You asked what the best way is, and you're being told. I don't see a problem or reason for "sheesh"ing.

Comment: @underscore_d Your tone comes off as snark, that's all. Regardless I'd rather not pollute the comments section with something this trivial, so I'll go ahead and stop replying now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What are the differences
>
> ```
> Foo foo1{4, 2};
> ```

This is [direct initialization (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

> Direct initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 2) during list-initialization sequence, if no initializer-list constructors are provided and a matching constructor is accessible, and all necessary implicit conversions are non-narrowing.

---

> ```
> Foo foo2 = {4, 2};
> ```

This is [copy list initialization (6)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Explicit constructors are not considered for non-direct list initialization. That explains why the program didn't compile when you changed the constructor explicit.

> copy-list-initialization (only non-explicit constructors may be called)
>
> 6) initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list after an equals sign

---

> ```
> Foo foo3 = Foo{4, 2};
> ```

This is [direct list initialization (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of a temporary object, then [copy initialization (1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the temporary.

> direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered)
>
> 2) initialization of an unnamed temporary with a braced-init-list
>
> ---
>
> Copy initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 2) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a non-reference type T is declared with the initializer consisting of an equals sign followed by an expression.

---

First is simplest and that is why I prefer it.

The second requires an implicit constructor, but is otherwise fine.

The third involves repeating of the type (violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), and constructs an unnecessary temporary (in practice, the copy may be elided by the optimizer, but the type must be copyable).

> I hear adding explicit to constructors is a Good Idea™. So I added explicit to the constructor of Foo

Adding explicit to single argument constructor is a good idea, if you want to prevent implicit conversions. Explicit isn't so universally useful for two argument constructors, but I don't doubt there could be situations where you'd need it.